# What are the maximum recommended layer height settings for a large but low detail model on an Elgoo Saturn?

Tags: layer-height

On an Elegoo Saturn resin printer, I'm going to print some background scenery. The models have large flat surfaces and little detail. I will add this later using traditional modelling methods.

I want to print these out as fast as is safe what is the maximum recommended layer height that I can use?